# Postfix Mail Server - Local accounts and external accounts - Forwarding

Tags: email, postfix-mta

This is the issue. I've a postfix mail server which has external email accounts (that exists on both my mailserver and my ISP) and internal use accounts (that only exists on my local mailserver).

The problem is when a local account tries to send an email to another local account which has a forward e-mail address configured. As the local account (the one who sends) has no authentication due to the lack of the ISP account, an error return everytime the only-local account sends an email to another local account which has an external forward configured.

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour? I don't want tons and tons of email-errors flushing back to the user's account.

Answer (score 2):

In your /etc/postfix/main.cf change the value of 'mydestination' to nothing ie ''
and 'virtual_alias_maps' to nothing ie ''